# Getting duplicated rows in my SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm facing a very strange problem I run a query like:

```
SELECT pif.Lat, pif.Lon, pif.IdPlaya, pif.NombrePlaya, ipm.marm, ipm.mart, ipm.marn,
       ipm.dirm, ipm.dirt, ipm.dirn, ipv.velmax_m, ipv.velmax_t, ipv.velmax_n,
       ipp.tmax, ipp.simbm, ipp.simbt, ipp.simbn,ipm.diaprev
FROM   meteo.dbo.SYS_PLATGES_INFO_FULL_TEMP Pif,
       meteo.dbo.in_previsio_poblacio Ipp,
       meteo.dbo.sys_platges_detall Spd,
       meteo.dbo.in_previsio_mars Ipm,
       meteo.dbo.in_previsio_vents Ipv
WHERE  Ipp.idpob = Pif.IdPoblacion
       AND Ipp.diaprev = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
       AND Spd.IdCiutat = Pif.IdPoblacion
       AND Ipm.id = Spd.IdCosta
       AND Ipm.diaprev = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
       AND Ipv.id_previsio = Pif.IdPoblacion
       AND Ipv.data_previsio = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
GROUP BY pif.NombrePlaya,pif.Lat,pif.Lon,pif.IdPlaya,ipm.marm,ipm.mart,ipm.marn
      ipm.dirm,ipm.dirt,ipm.dirn,ipv.velmax_m,ipv.velmax_t,ipv.velmax_n,ipp.idpob,
      ipp.tmax,ipp.simbm,ipp.simbt,ipp.simbn,ipm.diaprev
```

and for some tables there is a duplicated one like this:

[image: query result]

look at Del Torres, if you mention there is a different between these two (NE/SE). So i went to table which provide data for this column and searched for the records for the place ID in `meteo.dbo.in_previsio_mars` but only one record existed for the same date but after running the query there is 2 records for the date and there is no other records which contain

> NE E SE

if you had the same exprience i will appreciate if you share it with me.

**Update 1:**

tables structures
[image]

Comment: This is not a real answer to your question, just some good advice. Read the following thoroughly: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: meteo.dbo.in_previsio_mars certainly has to contain the 'NE E SE' combination you mention in a single row - as far as I can see - you need to check carefully, make sure you are looking at the correct database/table etc.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton it seems everything is right ... let me check everything again

Comment: @Blacksword: It's no possible you have only one row in in_previsio_mars where the field dirn has a value NE. Please post other rows of your table

Comment: @Blacksword: Post an entire set of rows of your tables. In the screenshot about tables structures, rows among tables are not referred to same functional entity

Comment: i update the pic for a same data set

Answer (score 1):

If you have in your `in_previsio_mars` table a link to `SYS_PLATGES_INFO_FULL_TEMP` table please add it in WHERE (JOIN) condition, as you have done with other table `in_previsio_vents`

In fact:

You have:

```
AND Ipv.id_previsio = Pif.IdPoblacion
```

If you can, add:

```
AND Ipm.id_previsio = Pif.IdPoblacion
```

Finally, I advice you to use an explicit JOIN notation as follow:

```
SELECT 
    pif.Lat, pif.Lon, pif.IdPlaya, pif.NombrePlaya,
    ipm.marm, ipm.mart, ipm.marn,
    ipm.dirm, ipm.dirt, ipm.dirn, ipv.velmax_m, ipv.velmax_t, ipv.velmax_n,
    ipp.tmax, ipp.simbm, ipp.simbt, ipp.simbn,ipm.diaprev
FROM meteo.dbo.SYS_PLATGES_INFO_FULL_TEMP Pif
   JOIN meteo.dbo.in_previsio_poblacio Ipp
       ON Ipp.idpob = Pif.IdPoblacion
   JOIN meteo.dbo.sys_platges_detall Spd
       ON Spd.IdCiutat = Pif.IdPoblacion
   JOIN meteo.dbo.in_previsio_mars Ipm
       ON Ipm.id = Spd.IdCosta
       AND Ipm.id_previsio = Pif.IdPoblacion
   JOIN meteo.dbo.in_previsio_vents Ipv
       ON Ipv.id_previsio = Pif.IdPoblacion
WHERE Ipp.diaprev = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
   AND Ipm.diaprev = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
   AND Ipv.data_previsio = '05-10-2016 0:00:00'
GROUP BY
    Pif.NombrePlaya,Pif.Lat,Pif.Lon,Pif.IdPlaya,Ipm.marm,
    Ipm.mart,Ipm.marn,Ipm.dirm,Ipm.dirt,Ipm.dirn,Ipv.velmax_m,
    Ipv.velmax_t,Ipv.velmax_n,Ipp.idpob,Ipp.tmax,Ipp.simbm,Ipp.simbt,
    Ipp.simbn,Ipm.diaprev
```

In this way you take under control the JOIN conditions and the WHERE conditions (in the INNER JOIN can be the same, but if you use OUTER JOIN meanings change)

Comment: let me update my post to show the structures of tables

Comment: @Blacksword: Ok, I'm here ;)

Comment: and also there is no Ipm.id_previsio exist

Comment: any answer on this finally?